# How to edit the code so that the results are as we expected?

Tags: php

My code is like this :

```
<?php

    function romanic_number($integer, $upcase = true) 
    { 
        $table = array('M'=>1000, 'CM'=>900, 'D'=>500, 'CD'=>400, 'C'=>100, 'XC'=>90, 'L'=>50, 'XL'=>40, 'X'=>10, 'IX'=>9, 'V'=>5, 'IV'=>4, 'I'=>1); 
        $return = ''; 
        while($integer > 0) 
        { 
            foreach($table as $rom=>$arb) 
            { 
                if($integer >= $arb) 
                { 
                    $integer -= $arb; 
                    $return .= $rom; 
                    break; 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        return $return; 
    } 

    $testArray = array(
            array(
                'display'   => '1', // strlen = 1 => it's Continent
                'uraian'    => 'European Continent',
            ),
            array(
                'display'   => '114', // strlen = 3 => it's Country
                'uraian'    => 'England Country',
            ),
            array(
                'display'   => '1141444', // strlen = 7 => it's City 
                'uraian'    => 'London City',
            ),
            array(
                'display'   => '1141445', 
                'uraian'    => 'Manchester City',
            ),
            array(
                'display'   => '1141452', 
                'uraian'    => 'Liverpool City',
            ),
            array(
                'display'   => '1141454', 
                'uraian'    => 'Oxford City',
            ),
            array(
                'display'   => '115', 
                'uraian'    => 'Spain Country',
            ),
            array(
                'display'   => '1151464', 
                'uraian'    => 'Madrid City',
            ),
            array(
                'display'   => '1151465', 
                'uraian'    => 'Barcelona City',
            ),
            array(
                'display'   => '2', 
                'uraian'    => 'Asian Continent',
            ),
            array(
                'display'   => '215', 
                'uraian'    => 'Japan Country',
            ),
            array(
                'display'   => '2151474', 
                'uraian'    => 'Tokyo City',
            ),
            array(
                'display'   => '2151475', 
                'uraian'    => 'Osaka City',
            )
        );

    echo '<table border=1>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>';
    $i = 1;
    $j = 'A';
    foreach($testArray as $key)
    {
        echo '<tr>
                <td>';
                    if(strlen($key['display'])==3)
                    {
                        echo romanic_number($i);
                        ++$i;
                    }
                    if(strlen($key['display'])==7)
                    {
                        echo $j;
                        ++$j;
                    }
        echo   '</td>
                <td>';
                    echo $key['uraian'];
        echo    '</td>
             </tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';

?>
```

The result is like this : http://postimg.org/image/9jmn7mlr1/

[image]

I want the result not like that, but like this:

https://postimg.org/image/579p02c1p/

[image]

I had try to edit the code, but i'm still can't do it.

Is there any people who can help me?

Comment: Will your array **always** be sorted by Continent/Country/City before you build your html code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do two things here:

- Reset both `$i` and `$j` variables once your `foreach` completes the traversal of one continent.
- Reset variable `$j` once the loop completes the traversal of every city of a country.

So your `foreach` loop should be like this:

```
foreach($testArray as $key){
    if(strlen($key['display'])==1){
        $i = 1; $j = 'A';
    }
    echo '<tr><td>';
        if(strlen($key['display'])==3){
            echo romanic_number($i);
            ++$i; 
            $j = 'A';
        }
        if(strlen($key['display'])==7){
            echo $j;
            ++$j;
        }
    echo '</td><td>';
        echo $key['uraian'];
    echo '</td></tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your array is always sorted properly by `Continent`/`Country`/`City` before you build your html code, then you can just reset the `$i`/`$j` counters when you come to a `Continent`

```
if(strlen($key['display'])==1) {$i = 1;$j = 'A';}
```

just place at the start of your loop

```
...
foreach($testArray as $key)
{
        if(strlen($key['display'])==1) {$i = 1;$j = 'A';}
...
```